# Multiple Views in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have an index page and three partial views. The index page is using ng-view for dynamically loading partial views. The partial views are called TestPartial1.html, TestPartial2.html and BothPartials.html. The BothPartials.html contains both TestPartial1.html and TestPartial2.html so that when BothPartials link is clicked ng-view calls BothPartials.html, which should load both TestPartial1.html and TestPartial2.html.

I am able to call and display TestPartial1.html and TestPartial2.html separately but I cannot figure out how to display both pages together through BothPartials.html. I have tried using ng-include in BothPartials.html for loading TestPartial1 and TestPartial2 but to no avail.

My code is as follows:

**Index.aspx**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-view id="ng-view"></div> 
</body>
```

**TestPartial1.html**

```
<div>
 <h1>View 1</h1><br />
 <a href="#View2">View2</a>
</div>
```

**TestPartial2.html**

```
<div>
 <h1>View 2</h1><br />
 <a href="#View1">View1</a>
 <a href="#BothViews">Both Views</a>
</div>
```

**BothPartials.html**

```
<div>
 <br />
 <br />
 test
 <div ng-include = "TestPartial1.html"></div>
 <div ng-include = "TestPartial2.html"></div>
</div>
```

**App.js**

```
(function () {
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);    
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Index.aspx', {
            templateUrl: 'PartialViews/TestPartial1.html'                
        })
        .when('/View1', {                
            templateUrl: 'PartialViews/TestPartial1.html'              
        })
        .when('/View2', {               
            templateUrl: 'PartialViews/TestPartial2.html'

        })
        .when('/BothViews', {
            templateUrl: 'PartialViews/BothPartials.html'

        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Index.aspx' });

}]);
}
)();
```

Comment: Could be because your `ng-include` is a relative path. Try absolute path: `ng-include="/PartialViews/TestPartial1.html"`

Comment: If you want multiple views it might be better to use ui-router in long run

Comment: @Coop I have tried following different combinations but of no use: "~/Restricted/PartialViews/TestPartial1.html", "/PartialViews/TestPartial1.html", "/TestPartial1.html"

Comment: Is there an error visible in the console?

Comment: @Coop, there is no error in the console. I have taken maurycy's advise and using ui-router. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

give proper path for the TestPartial1.html and TestPartial2.html in ng-include.

Comment: I have tried following different combinations but of no use: "~/Restricted/PartialViews/TestPartial1.html", "/PartialViews/TestPartial1.html", "/TestPartial1.html"